# Project with Guava, GWT and AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, guava

Is it possible to use the [Guava libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) on a project done with both GWT and Google AppEngine?

I see that the individual `jars` (the standard Java one and the GWT compatible one) have the same package naming hierarchy.  How do these integrate in a GWT+AppEngine projecT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  A few Guava classes won't be usable on AppEngine because of the restricted sandbox your app will run in, especially those in the .io package like Files (you will be able to read stuff but not write it).

Are you worried about deploying both jar files and having a conflict?  If so, I think it will be fine - when you compile your GWT application, it turns into javascript, so you wouldn't necessarily be deploying the GWT compatible jar, just the normal one.

Comment: thanks for your contribution.  So, if I just drop the "gwt" one in my Eclipse project, I'll be good for both GWT and AppEngine?

Comment: I believe so.  There may be a small amount of classes that you miss by doing this however - assuming that there exist classes that both works in app engine but are not gwt compatible.  If you look at the javadoc for the guava libraries, you can see that many (most?) of them are annotated with @gwt-compatible.  For example see http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ranges.html

Answer (score 2):

There won't be any conflict as the gwt one will be used by true DevMode client-side and the GWT compiler, the "normal " one will live in your WEB-INF/lib and be loaded (in DevMode) in a different classloader. It thus depends entirely on your project and build setup.

That being said I never tried it within the same Eclipse project. I always use distinct client and server projects, and -noserver in DevMode.